# How to get max value of lubridate time object from a variable of a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which includes timed data, the time column includes object of `lubridate::hms()`, now how can get the max time object value from the variable time in R.

[image: Snapshot of the data frame]
I was trying do it by this basic approach, but it returns value in double format->

```
> max(comdty1$Time)
[1] 59.99531
```

also this is fine

```
> max(lubridate::hour(comdty1$Time))
[1] 17
```

TIA

Comment: Did you try `max(lubridate::hms(comdty1$Time))`?

Comment: Does'nt works....



> max(hms(comdty1$Time))
[1] NA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with

```
# get the maximum hour
maxHour1 <- max(hour(comdty1$Time))
# get the corresponding complete time object
tail(comdty1$Time[which(hour(comdty1$Time)==TmaxHour)],1)
```